# Check if user exists for Password Reset - Devise . Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

and devise, i make a test on the reset password function, everything is working fine, there is just one issue

If i delete a user, he still can ask for his password, the link inside the email, dosent work, but, how can i check if the user exists first, before sending the email, im just using this.

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
```

I also have pulled up the views, but , how can i check this.

Comment: You don't have to check this explicitly, devise takes care of it it will throw and error if email does not exist before sending an reset password token

Answer (score 0):

Try using

**before_filter :authenticate_user!**

in application controller and try again.

Answer (score 0):

A public user still has access to the "Forget password" page and can still provide an email to send to. However, this email has to exist in your DB for the reset_password_instructions email to be sent to that email. If the public user has no account with your application, the email won't be sent. If, however, the public user guesses a correct email, he would need to find a way to access that email. :)

In short, you don't need to check if the user exists.

Comment: As i said, i test, if a user is deleted, even when he is deleted the email is sent to his email, but the link doesnt work, because the account does not exist.. i want to avoid sending that email..// A meesage with "we could not find that account" would be awesome